# Left recurion (direct and indirect) eliminating in JavaCC

Tags: java, parsing, recursion, grammar, javacc

I have a problem with eliminating left recursions in JavaCC. I found a solution with [Epsilon tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion), but it seems that JavaCC is not able to work very well with Epsilon tokens (like `TOKEN : <eps : "">`). Below I prepare an example of my issue:

```
void prod1() : 
{}
{
    <beta1>
    | prod2() <alpha1>
}

void prod2() : 
{}
{
    <beta2>
    | [prod2()] <alpha2>
    | prod1() <alpha3>
}
```

Here we see both direct and undirect left recursion. It is a simplified example of my real grammar (My JavaCC grammar is based on existing BNF grammar, hence I forced to use it in such form).

Comment: The second alternative for `prod2` is just `prod2`.  I suspect a typo.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed this typo

Comment: It is necessary to change the grammar (without changing the language). In many cases you can use iteration (`{ ... }`) to resolve recursions.

Comment: In JavaCC epsilons can be entered as `{ }`.  Epsilons aren't really tokens, but represent a sequence of 0 tokens.  The syntax of JavaCC doesn't allow an alternative to be empty, but you can put in a Java block that contains no Java code, which is what `{ }` is.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, and it seems to be fit for me.

```
void prod1() : 
{}
{
    <beta1>
    | prod2() <alpha1>
}

void prod2() : 
{}
{
    <beta2>
    | [prod2()] <alpha2> // (1)
    | prod1() <alpha3>
}
```

Step 1. Expand (1)

```
void prod1() : 
{}
{
    <beta1>
    | prod2() <alpha1>
}

void prod2() : 
{}
{
    <beta2>
    | <alpha2>
    | prod2() <alpha2>
    | prod1() <alpha3>
}
```

Step 2. Insert the prod1 inside of the prod2

```
void prod1() : 
{}
{
    <beta1>
    | prod2() <alpha1>
}

void prod2() : 
{}
{
    <beta2>
    | <alpha2>
    | prod2() <alpha2>
    | <beta1> <alpha3>
    | prod2() <alpha1> <alpha3>
}
```

Step 3. Eliminate left recursion in prod2 with epsilon productions (described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion)

```
void prod1() : 
{}
{
    <beta1>
    | prod2() <alpha1>
}

void prod2() : 
{}
{
    <beta2> prod2_()
    | <alpha2> prod2_()
    | <beta1> <alpha3> prod2_()
}

void prod2_() :
{}
{
    prod2() <alpha2> prod2_()
    | prod2() <alpha1> <alpha3> prod2_()
    | <epsilon>
}
```

Step 4. Eliminate epsilon productions from prod2_() (described here http://www.d.umn.edu/~hudson/5641/l11m.pdf)

```
void prod1() : 
{}
{
    <beta1>
    | prod2() <alpha1>
}

void prod2() : 
{}
{
    <beta2> [prod2_()]
    | <alpha2> [prod2_()]
    | <beta1> <alpha3> [prod2_()]
}

void prod2_() :
{}
{
    prod2() <alpha2> [prod2_()]
    | prod2() <alpha1> <alpha3> [prod2_()]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the third step.  I think the calls to prod2 in prod2_ should not be there.  I.e. you want `void prod2_() : {} { <alpha2> prod2_() | <alpha1> <alpha3> prod2()_ | {} }`.  (Also, note the use of `{}` for epsilon in JavaCC.)

Answer (score 0):

```
prod1 --> beta1 | prod2 alpha1
prod2 --> beta2 | [prod2] alpha2 | prod1 alpha3
```

Expand the option

```
prod1 --> beta1 | prod2 alpha1
prod2 --> beta2 | alpha2 | prod2 alpha2 | prod1 alpha3
```

Replace prod1 in prod2

```
prod1 --> beta1 | prod2 alpha1
prod2 --> beta2 | alpha2 | prod2 alpha2 | (beta1 | prod2 alpha1) alpha3
```

Distribute

```
prod1 --> beta1 | prod2 alpha1
prod2 --> beta2 | alpha2 | prod2 alpha2 | beta1 alpha3 | prod2 alpha1 alpha3
```

Rearrange and factor

```
prod1 --> beta1 | prod2 alpha1
prod2 --> (beta2 | alpha2 | beta1 alpha3) | prod2 (alpha2 | alpha1 alpha3)
```

Eliminate left recursion

```
prod1 --> beta1 | prod2 alpha1
prod2 --> (beta2 | alpha2 | beta1 alpha3) (alpha2 | alpha1 alpha3)*
```